# How do I resolve a mysql Thread Stack Overrun?

Tags: mysql, linode

I have a stored procedure on mysql.  It worked on my local MAMP environment, the procedure worked well, but when I moved it to a linode server/host it does not run.  I'm getting a "Thread Stack Overrun" error.  I have tried upping the thread stack up from an initial value 64K.  I changed the value to 128K then to 256K.  but the problem still occurs.

i am working on a lucid ubuntu 512MB linode server.  I am running on linode's suggested configuration in my mysql/my.cnf file:

```
key_buffer = 16K
max_allowed_packet = 1M
thread_stack = 64K 
table_cache = 4
sort_buffer = 64K
net_buffer_length = 2K
```

Can anyone help?  Can you suggest different configurations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was an idiot.  I reset the thread_stack to a higher number, but i didn't restart the server.  restarting resolved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Ubuntu 14.04 you can increase your MySQL thread stack here:

`/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

and change this value `thread_stack` which might have a value like this, for example:

`thread_stack            = 192K`

After that you need to restart MySQL like so:

`sudo service mysql restart`

Refer to the [Ubuntu 14.04, MySQL documentatio](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/serverguide/mysql.html)n for more info.

Comment: In Ubuntu-16.04.3 the file location and name changed.  I had to run `sudo gedit /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` to change the value of `thread_stack`.

Comment: Also, on Ubuntu 16.04 restart MySQL with: `sudo systemctl restart mysql.service`

Comment: I already had this in my my.cnf but the value was too low. Setting it to 192 fixed it so thanks for the direction!