# Remove all occurrences of ids from comma separated string in single MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

| id | shop_id | collection_id | collection_title | product_ids | created_on | updated_on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20735 | 50 | 263607681176 | Home page |  | 2021-04-09T01:06:13Z | 2021-04-13T23:26:14Z |
| 20736 | 50 | 264253735064 | Summer Collection | 6623623413912,6623624822936,6623625085080,6623624691864,6623624659096,6623623741592,6623623610520,6623623577752 | 2021-04-09T01:06:13Z | 2022-03-30T06:58:34Z |
| 20737 | 50 | 264253736541 | Winter Collection | 6623624822936,6623625085080,6623624691864,6623624659096 | 2021-04-09T01:06:13Z | 2022-03-30T06:58:34Z |
| 20738 | 70 | 264253767832 | Under $100 | 6623623413912,6623625085080,6623624822936,6623624790168,6623623905432,6623623872664,6623623839896,6623623774360 | 2021-04-09T01:06:13Z | 2021-04-13T23:26:14Z |

My input ids are:

```
6623625085080
6623624659096
```

I want a table like this after a query (passed ids should be removed from the table):

| id | shop_id | collection_id | collection_title | product_ids | created_on | updated_on |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20735 | 50 | 263607681176 | Home page |  | 2021-04-09T01:06:13Z | 2021-04-13T23:26:14Z |
| 20736 | 50 | 264253735064 | Summer Collection | 6623623413912,6623624822936,6623624691864,6623623741592,6623623610520,6623623577752 | 2021-04-09T01:06:13Z | 2022-03-30T06:58:34Z |
| 20737 | 50 | 264253736541 | Winter Collection | 6623624822936,6623624691864 | 2021-04-09T01:06:13Z | 2022-03-30T06:58:34Z |
| 20738 | 70 | 264253767832 | Under $100 | 6623623413912,6623625085080,6623624822936,6623624790168,6623623905432,6623623872664,6623623839896,6623623774360 | 2021-04-09T01:06:13Z | 2021-04-13T23:26:14Z |

I have already used this query and it works for the single `product_ids` in there:

```
UPDATE collections SET product_ids = TRIM(BOTH ',' FROM REPLACE(CONCAT(',', product_ids, ','), ',6623625085080,', ',')) WHERE FIND_IN_SET('6623625085080', product_ids) AND shop_id = 50;
```

But, I want to do that by passing multiple `product_ids` in a single Update query.

Here you can see this screenshot, that I have tested,
[image: attachment of phpmyadmin]

And here is the SQL Fiddle link also: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bba9ff/1

Comment: Is it too late to redesign the database properly with normalisation applied?

Comment: i agree with RiggsFolly sir.  [FIND_IN_SET() can search for single value but answer has workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51335920/find-in-set-with-multiple-value)

Comment: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad? "**TL;DR- YES**"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: How would you suggest designing the database? @RiggsFolly

Comment: Google _"relational database design for beginners"_

Comment: basically wherever a csv seems the answer is should not be. Instead if you want to link one thing to many other things that already exist a LINK TABLE is what you should be thinking about. A simple table like, for example, table name `collection_products` has 2 columns `collections_id, product_id`

Comment: Sorry, My friend But this database design is too old for that. and I want to go with the question that I posted. @RiggsFolly

Comment: What's the input type? Is it a table? Is it possible for the input to be a single string containing the product ids to be removed, separated by comma?

Comment: @lemon, in this input type, could be an array, and I think it can be possible. I just have to go with the flow in it. and I am currently working on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is crafting a function that

- given a comma-separated original string of products and
- given a comma-separated string of to-be-removed products,

outputs the remaining products from the first string of products.

Once you get this function, you can use it into your `UPDATE` statement avoiding overcomplexity in it.

The function I was thinking is the following one:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS remove_product_ids;
CREATE FUNCTION remove_product_ids (
    all_products        VARCHAR(500), 
    products_to_remove  VARCHAR(500)
)
RETURNS 
    VARCHAR(500) 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE num_products    INT        DEFAULT LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(products_to_remove, '[^,]', ''))+1;
    DECLARE product         CHAR(13);

    WHILE num_products > 0 DO
        SET product = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(products_to_remove, ",", num_products), ',', -1);
        SET all_products = REGEXP_REPLACE(all_products, CONCAT(product, ',|,', product), '');
        SET num_products = num_products - 1;
    END WHILE;

    RETURN all_products;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The while you can see here, loops over the number of products to be removed. The three operations that are carried out in there are:

1. extracting the product to remove from the products_to_remove string
2. removing the product from the all_products original string
3. updating the number of products to be removed

Once you get it working, you are able to call the `UPDATE` function like this:

```
SET @input_ids = '6623625085080,6623624659096';

UPDATE 
    collections 
SET 
    product_ids = remove_product_ids(product_ids, @input_ids);
```

Running the script into SQLFiddle will put two problems in place:

1. SQLFiddle is unable to process delimiters ([Execute triggers stored procedures on SqlFiddle. Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166380/execute-triggers-stored-procedures-on-sqlfiddle-mysql/12166866#12166866)), hence it requires us to change all ';' to '//' and select the different kind of delimiter from the options (though if you work with your mysql client, it should recognize 'DELIMITER')
2. If you run the update function along with the creation of the function, it fires a 'Thread stack overrun' exception, which can be fixed by specifying a higher number for the stack memory. This is something you can't do within SQLFiddle, but you would be able to alter that value for your mysql client (in case you need it), changing the variable 'thread_stack' in the 'my.cnf' file found in your mysql folder, like pointed in this stack overflow thread [How do I resolve a mysql Thread Stack Overrun?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376725/how-do-i-resolve-a-mysql-thread-stack-overrun).

Here's the SQLFiddle I've run: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40cb18.

Comment: Hello @lemon, Could you make a fiddle with my example?. I think I am not getting it.

Comment: @Hitesh I've updated the answer because it was too long as a comment to be published. Feel free to ask for further questions.